# angularjs ng-options with date formatting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to format date in `ng-options`, the formatting is working well but I am unable to bind the value to the controller. I am getting value as undefined. Am I doing any mistake ?

```
<select class="select" ng-model="classdate"  ng-init="classdate=''"  ng-options="d.date as d.value | date:'d,MMM,yyyy' for d in datelist" >
<option value="">Select lecture date</option>
</select>
```

In controller

```
alert($scope.classdate);
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code and have you correctly included your controller in the html markup?

Comment: @Yatin i think the problem is with formatting because when iremove formatting it works as usual!

Comment: Are you saying that it works by removing the `class="select"` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `as d.value` after the date formatting:

```js
angular.module('mymodule', [])
  .controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.classdateUpdated = function() {
      console.log($scope.classdate);
    };
    $scope.datelist = [new Date(2000, 01, 01), new Date(2000, 02, 01), new Date(2000, 03, 01), new Date(2000, 04, 01), new Date(2000, 05, 01), new Date(2000, 06, 01), new Date(2000, 07, 01)];
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='mymodule'>
  <div ng-controller='mycontroller'>
    <select class="select" ng-model="classdate" ng-init="classdate=''" ng-options="d | date:'d,MMM,yyyy' for d in datelist" ng-change="classdateUpdated()">
      <option value="">Select lecture date</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling `alert($scope.classdate);`? If you are calling it on init, it will show undefined because you have used `ng-init="classdate=''"`. If you want to see the value changing as you select different options, add an `ng-change` attribute.

```
<select class="select" ng-model="classdate"  ng-init="classdate=''" ng-change="classdateUpdated()"  ng-options="d.date as d.value | date:'d,MMM,yyyy' for d in datelist">
<option value="">Select lecture date</option>
</select>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.classdateUpdated = function() {
    console.log($scope.classdate);
};
```

Now you will see the value of $scope.classdate every time it is updated.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested function for logging the value but please remove the () from the classdateUpdated() - it will not work.

Comment: No worries. I've used your function in my code that I posted.